# How to get Google to index based on my iframe <title> not the full page <title>

Tags: javascript, html, search, indexing, iframe

Simplicticly, my site contains a list of items, read from the database, in a left hand panel. The user can select an item and the full details of the item are displayed in the center panel, which is an iframe.

The reason for the iframe is so that the whole page doesn't have to be refreshed which would mean re-reading the database to re-generate the item list - I just need one read to get the item details and the list is left on the screen for subsequent selection.

The sql to genereate the item list is actually quite complex and the volumes could be quite high, so it really doesn't make sense from an architetural perspective to re-generate the whole page each time an item is selected.

From the user perspective each item selected generates entirely new/different content in the center panel.

My problem is that Google seems to have problems indexing this. In particular I believe that Google takes account of the 'title' of the main page, which is always the same, but probably ignores the 'title' of the iframe 'page' which has the real content and the specific title of the real content.

I don't believe it's logically possible to generate the real content specific title for the main page without re-generating the main page and hence having to re-read the database.
Is there any way to get google to use the iframe page 'title' which correctly describes the content?

Thanks.

Comment: sounds like you should be utilizing caching on the backend.

Comment: Thanks epascarello. I am now looking into that as a Plan B. However, I don't feel it is an elegant solution and it will cause me other problems (and more work!). I haven't quite given up on finding another solution, but not hopefull.

Comment: reason why we stopped using framed sites in the 90s :)

Answer (score 0):

Clearly it is not possible to refresh the main page 'title' without refreshing the page and therefore refreshing the iframe that contains the results of a significant database read.

Also, there is no way to get Google to use and iframe 'title' in preference to the main page.

So, I have to go with the comment made by epascarello: refresh the main page and think about caching to overcome any performance hit due to additional database reads.

I have now changed the system to refresh the main page, and for the time being (with low activity level) I've not implemented specific caching.

I am still slightly annoyed at what I think is a sub-optimal approach. I don't like the tell-tale blip in the menu as it is unnecessarily refreshed. There is also a bit of collateral damage as the refresh does not leave the user in the same (expansion) position when list is collapsible - i.e. it is refreshed to fully collapsed.

I now need to research the best way to do caching for when activity grows. Rather than jump straight in and use the PHP caching functions, it dawns on me that automatic caching could take place in a number of places without me doing anything: MySQL; PHP; Apache; Browser - where do I start to try and understand all this?